# How can I access void on the script of the object found in Tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
//Like for example:
public GameObject[] enemy;

//In the void Start()
enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

//I want access void "animateEnemy()" to all object that has tag "Enemy"
//Note that: All of my game object with a tag "Enemy" has a void "AnimateEnemy()"
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and first get the component that contains the said void. Example:

```
foreach(var enemy in enemies)
{
   enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().AnimateEnemy();
}
```

Note that I changed the original `enemy` to `enemies` since what you are getting from `FindGameObjectWithTag()` is an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks!!! This solves my problem :)

Comment: Would appreciate if you could mark it as the answer :)